# App crashes on release version: ReferenceError: Can't find variable

Tags: android, react-native

I came upon a weird issue. Everything works perfectly fine on debug version. But when I build the release version, it will crash. I use a library react-native-root-toast for toasts, but I'm not sure if it's a library's fault.

With adb logcat I managed to get a log:

```
01-28 12:25:59.571 12750 12771 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.cjournal, PID: 12750
01-28 12:25:59.571 12750 12771 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: toast, stack:
01-28 12:25:59.571 12750 12771 E AndroidRuntime: showToast@686:121
01-28 12:25:59.571 12750 12771 E AndroidRuntime: default@680:617
01-28 12:25:59.571 12750 12771 E AndroidRuntime: @397:3871
01-28 12:25:59.571 12750 12771 E AndroidRuntime: j@397:5845
```

The code that implements toasts:

```js
import Toast from 'react-native-root-toast'

export function showToast(message) {
    toast(message, '#005500')
}

export function showError(message) {
    toast(message, '#550000')
}

function toast(message, color) {
    let toast = Toast.show(message, {
        duration: Toast.durations.LONG,
        position: Toast.positions.BOTTOM,
        shadow: true,
        animation: true,
        hideOnPress: true,
        delay: 0,
        backgroundColor: color,
        onShow: () => {
            // calls on toast\`s appear animation start
        },
        onShown: () => {
            // calls on toast\`s appear animation end.
        },
        onHide: () => {
            // calls on toast\`s hide animation start.
        },
        onHidden: () => {
            // calls on toast\`s hide animation end.
        },
    })
}
```

On debug, it's perfectly fine. On release, it crashes. For now, I turned off the call of the function `showToast`, and now it doesn't crash. So my question is can I fix it or not. Since it's working in the debug, I suppose the library is fine and there's something wrong with my build.

Comment: cna you share some code where have you implemnted toast so that we can check

Comment: Sure. I updated the question with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with changing function to fat arrow like my code below and putting that function in top , coz during debug mode it uses a different engine to process JS data, so try this out:

```
import Toast from 'react-native-root-toast';

const toast = (message, color) =>  {
    let toast = Toast.show(message, {
        duration: Toast.durations.LONG,
        position: Toast.positions.BOTTOM,
        shadow: true,
        animation: true,
        hideOnPress: true,
        delay: 0,
        backgroundColor: color,
        onShow: () => {
            // calls on toast\`s appear animation start
        },
        onShown: () => {
            // calls on toast\`s appear animation end.
        },
        onHide: () => {
            // calls on toast\`s hide animation start.
        },
        onHidden: () => {
            // calls on toast\`s hide animation end.
        },
    })
}
export function showToast(message) {
    toast(message, '#005500')
}

export function showError(message) {
    toast(message, '#550000')
}
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for the fix and for the information. I will keep it in mind from now on.